# Cannot Transfer File using scp command for certificate authority

Tags: ssh, vpn, openvpn, certificates

So I trying to setup OpenVPN on my Ubuntu 20.04. I am using this online article ([How to setup a OpenVPN server on Ubuntu 20.04](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-setup-a-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-20-04)) that was recommended to me to set up a VPN with the Certificate Authority. I am stuck in this area:

```
scp -v pki/reqs/server.req  krillavilla@camachine:/home/krillavilla/
```

This is my result:

```
Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host camachine, user krillavilla, command scp -v -t /home/krillavilla/
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
ssh: Could not resolve hostname camachine: Name or service not known
lost connection
```

Comment: The response says that your computer cannot determine what is the IP of camachine. Therefore, it does not know where to connect to. If you try `ping camachine` you will see that your computer will report that camachine address is unknown. Oh, I see that camachine is directly from the examples you provided. You should exchange it with your server.

Comment: You should copy certificate request to signing server, if you have one. otherwise sign it where it was created.

Answer (score 0):

Accord to the article. you need two machines to complete VPN server.